Почему получаются разные результаты conditional type, когда приходят одинаковые union types. При этом эти union types были получены разным способом
Я написал два своих Await-а для промиса, но один почему-то не работает. И выводит тип never
type MyAwaitF<T> = T extends null | undefined
  ? never
  : T extends object & { then(...args: infer Arg): any }
  ? Arg[0] extends (value: infer V) => unknown
    ? V
    : never
  : never;

type MyAwaitS<T> = T extends null | undefined
  ? never
  : T extends object & { then(f: infer F): any }
  ? F extends (value: infer V) => unknown
    ? V
    : never
  : never;

type ResF = MyAwaitF<Promise<string>>; // never 
type ResS = MyAwaitS<Promise<string>>; // string

Я пробовал получить типы Arg[0] и F.
В первом случае
Arg[0] имеет union type ((value: string) => unknown) | null | undefined
Во втором случае
F имеет ((value: string) => unknown) | null | undefined
Но третий conditional в MyAwaitF  возвращает разные результаты.
В чем может быть проблема?
